# How to change the linux startup services order in SUSE 11

Tags: linux, opensuse, sles10

In RedHat and Centos changing the startup scripts as [stated](https://serverfault.com/posts/comments/947975?noredirect=1) here worked perfectly fine.

But Suse seems to follow different rules, if so what are the changes need to be taken into consideration?

Do "CHKCONFIG" in init scripts will have any effect of the starting order of services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Suse start and stop order of services are managed by **insserv** package and based on dependency with other services. So it is little different. The answer to your question is given in details with examples in the following Suse article:

[Manipulating the start and stop order of Linux services](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7002295)

> Under the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) (Linux Standards Base), the start and stop order of
> services is controlled using the "insserv" package. Unlike Netware,
> DOS and other operating systems, SUSE calculates the start and stop
> orders based on dependencies. This idiosyncrasy of Linux has the
> distinct advantage of providing a faster boot time, but does make
> things a little more complex.
>
> examples
>
> Here are few examples of how to manipulate the header of a service
> defined in /etc/init.d.
>
> The following example will start Service "myService" after the network
> has loaded and will automatically start the service "myOtherService"
>
> ```
> ### BEGIN INIT INFO
> # Provides:        myService
> # Required-Start: $network
> # Should-Start:   myOtherService
> # Required-Stop:
> # Should-Stop:
> # Default-Start:  2 3 5
> # Default-Stop:
> # Description:    Example Service
> ### END INIT INFO
> ```